# Codeigniter pagination script is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have many  records in my database I'm trying to display a single record for each page.When i select submit buttor to search records from database first single record is getting display and then when i click next numeric link of pagination iam not getting any result instead iam getting

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: controllers/searchresult.php
Line Number: 17
```

**My controller starts here**

```
public function users($limit=1)
 {
 $this->load->helper('url');
    $data = array();
    $offset=1;
    $look = $this->input->post('look');
    $age = $this->input->post('age');
    $age_from = $this->input->post('age_from');
    $age_to = $this->input->post('age_to');
    $se_ct = $this->input->post('sect');
    $subsect = $this->input->post('subsect');
    $coun_try = $this->input->post('country');
    $sta_te = $this->input->post('state');
    $ci_ty = $this->input->post('city');
    $qualification = $this->input->post('qualification');
    $results = $this->searchresultss->login($look, $age, $age_to, $age_from, $se_ct, $subsect, $coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty, $qualification);
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'searchresult/users';
    $config['total_rows'] = count($results);
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $this->load->library('pagination', $config);
    $data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['results'] = array_slice($results,$offset,$limit);
$this->load->view('searchresult', $data);
}

**my model page starts here**

 public function login($look, $age, $age_to, $age_from, $se_ct, $subsect, $coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty, $qualification)
            {
return $this->db->query("SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE  

if('$se_ct'!='',sect =  '$se_ct' AND if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
AND
IF( '$coun_try' !='', country =  '$coun_try'
AND 
if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
AND  
if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
AND state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
AND age >=  '$age_from'
AND age <=  '$age_to'
AND 
IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 
AND gender =  '$look'
And status='1'")->result();
            }     
}

**My view page starts here**

if (empty($results)) {
    echo 'Results set is empty';
} else {
foreach ($results as $data) {
        echo $data->email.'<br />';
    }
}
echo $pagination_links;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you have in the line number 17, but I can help you in something, You need to do:

```
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

to make pagination start working, you are missing that line. Pagination is not initialized in your code.

Comment: Call to a member function initialize() on a non-object is what iam getting

Comment: i removed $this->pagination->initialize($config);  and tried again by select next link of pagination iam getting emty result

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with another tip: You must send the offset to the model to make the db query. And you must to re-send the search fields, if you are clicking over one of the pagination links, the post data no longer exists in the next call, therefore you lost the searched values.

I fixed that problem before with a little jquery trick. The pagination links have to re-send the form and not be just a link. Something like

```
$('.pagination a').click(function(){

    $('#your-form').submit();
});
```

In other way you must to pass all the search again by the querystring, and that method is really ugly and makes your controller confusing and full of "ifs"

Comment: ok has iam new can you make changes and submit i will be thankfl if you do so

Comment: waiting for the response ..please help me